# Android designer moves elements to the top-right if edited

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a Problem in the designer (layout editor), if im in the designer first everything works fine until i sart editing any element. If i edit any of my Elements all the Elements just get moved to the top-Right of the layout Editor.

[Before editing any element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IzBvF.png) [After editing any element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ksV7C.png)

**activity**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Activity_booking_bookings">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:hint="@string/oper_name"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:hint="@string/wo_no"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TableLayout

        android:id="@+id/table1"
        android:layout_width="416dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:stretchColumns="0,1,2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="-2dp">

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"

            android:background="#000000">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:layout_margin="1dp"
                android:background="#FFFFFF"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/reject_code"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="40pt"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:layout_margin="1dp"
                android:background="#FFFFFF"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/qty"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="40pt"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_column="2"
                android:layout_margin="1dp"
                android:background="#FFFFFF"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/Path"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="40pt"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_column="2"
                android:layout_margin="1dp"
                android:background="#FFFFFF"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/check"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </TableRow>


    </TableLayout>

    <TableLayout

        android:id="@+id/table2"
        android:layout_width="409dp"
        android:layout_height="230dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:stretchColumns="0,1,2"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/btn_home"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"

            android:background="#000000">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:layout_margin="1dp"
                android:background="#FFFFFF"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="40pt"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:layout_margin="1dp"
                android:background="#FFFFFF"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/m_wo"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="40pt"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_column="2"
                android:layout_margin="1dp"
                android:background="#FFFFFF"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/s_wo"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="40pt"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_column="2"
                android:layout_margin="1dp"
                android:background="#FFFFFF"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/op"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#000000">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:layout_margin="1dp"
                android:background="#FFFFFF"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/prod"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:layout_margin="1dp"
                android:background="#FFFFFF"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/text"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:layout_margin="1dp"
                android:background="#FFFFFF"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/text"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_column="2"
                android:layout_margin="1dp"
                android:background="#FFFFFF"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/text"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
        </TableRow>


        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#000000">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:layout_margin="1dp"
                android:background="#FFFFFF"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/blank"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:layout_margin="1dp"
                android:background="#FFFFFF"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/text"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:layout_margin="1dp"
                android:background="#FFFFFF"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/text"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_column="2"
                android:layout_margin="1dp"
                android:background="#FFFFFF"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/text"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#000000">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:layout_margin="1dp"
                android:background="#FFFFFF"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/good"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:layout_margin="1dp"
                android:background="#FFFFFF"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/text"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:layout_margin="1dp"
                android:background="#FFFFFF"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/text"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_column="2"
                android:layout_margin="1dp"
                android:background="#FFFFFF"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/text"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#000000">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:layout_margin="1dp"
                android:background="#FFFFFF"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/scrap"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:layout_margin="1dp"
                android:background="#FFFFFF"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/text"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:layout_margin="1dp"
                android:background="#FFFFFF"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/text"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_column="2"
                android:layout_margin="1dp"
                android:background="#FFFFFF"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/text"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
        </TableRow>


    </TableLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_home"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="162dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="162dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="162dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="162dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:text="@string/home"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_next2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="57dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="57dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:onClick="onClick_next_activity3"
        android:text="@string/next"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/btn_home" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_back"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="58dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="58dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:onClick="onClick_back_MainActivity"
        android:text="@string/back"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/btn_home"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fa_btn_plus"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="47dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="234dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/table2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/table1"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_input_add" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Post your layout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use RelativeLayout if you want to place the UI elements as per your wish or else use LinearLayout to set your views either vertically or horizontally!
Don't use Constraint* Layout as you are new to android. It is a little bit of complicated!

Comment: Im not using Coordinator Layout, im using Constraint Layout

Comment: The Problem is i Need constraint Layout for my Design.

Comment: Constraint Layout is a type of different layouts. Unless you dont have a strong reason for using Constraint Layout I would suggest to use Relative or Linear

Comment: But is it even possible to make my Layout (1st Picture) as RelativeLayout or LinearLayout?

Comment: Use Relative Layout that would be pretty easier and a beauty to watch!
Please mark the answer if useful!

Comment: Its still not working, not even if i use Relative Layout

Comment: Before learn about RelativeLayout....Its different from Constraint Layout

Comment: Yes i know, but im not able to build the design i have to with Relative or Linear Layout.

Comment: Keep the parent layout as Relative! rest keep the same!

Comment: Yes thats exactly what i did… But if i do, the activity is completely different to how it was with constraintlayout. If i choose Relative Layout every element is moving to the top of the activity and i can't move it back.

Comment: 1. remove constraint related all attributes from the xml layout.
2.  android:layout_below="@+id/textlayout_lock" use the code to make and adjust your code

Comment: Ok i understand now, now it works thanks for your help. : )

Comment: Happy to Help! :) Welcome to the community @CyrillAugustiny :)